# Mixing UnityEngine.Debug and System.Diagnostics.Debug

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

I'm attaching the Visual Studio debugger to Unity3D to debug my code.

I would like to both

- output log message to the Unity Console
- as well as break Visual Studio in case of an exception. For example like this...

  Shader nLaserShader = Shader.Find("Particles/Additive");
  if (nLaserShader == null)
  {
   UnityEngine.Debug.Log("No laser shader!\n");
   System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
  }

I have to use the UnityEngine namespace, else VS doesn't compile my code and says that Debug.Log is ambiguous.

Is there a way to avoid typing full namespaces?

Comment: Do you have a `using System.Diagnostics;` directive in your code? Otherwise you shouldn't have a name clash

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes, I do because I wanted to be able to insert a break to stop the IDE. I tried to use Debugger.Break() (which doesn't work yet for some reason), and this required me to have "using System.Diagnostic".

Comment: But in the code snippet you posted you use the fully qualified name `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` which in turn means you don't need the `using` directive. Alternatively you could create an alias for the Unity one, e.g.: `using UnityDebug = UnityEngine.Debug;` and then call it as `UnityDebug.Log`

Comment: I used the qualified names to make it clear which debug(ger) I actually mean. Thank you for the hint on the alias! :-)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK The only way you can avoid having to type the entire namespace every time you need to make a call to something that is ambiguous is by adding an alias to the namespace. You will still need to type *something*  but atleast you can shorten it down to whatever length you want. The syntax for it is easy.

`using diag = System.Diagnostics;`

Will allow you to call `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` by simply typing `diag.Debbuger.Break();`, while being able to call `Debug.Log()` as you're used to.

```
using UnityEngine;
using diag = System.Diagnostics;

public class AmbiguousNamespace: MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject foo = GameObject.Find("bar");
        if (foo == null)
        {       
            Debug.Log("failed to find bar!");
            diag.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you don't want to use namespaces as it might obscure what namespace you are using, but still want to be able to save some time by not having to type out the entire System.Diagno... blablabla you can also take a look at making a [custom snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2017) for it.

This will allow you to set a keyword for it, and autocomplete with tab. for example you could make a snippet "sddb" which autocompletes to `System.Diagnostics.Debbuger.Break();` upon hitting tab. which I always find a good midground between readability and not having to type long things out every time.